# Super hard Euclidean Geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The triangle $ABC$ is right angld at $A$. A line through the midpoint $D$ of $BC$ meets $AB$ at $X$ and $AC$ at $Y$. The point $P$ is taken on this line so that $PD$ and $XY$ have the same midpoint $M$. The perpendicular from $P$ to $BC$ meets $BC$ at T.

Prove that $AM$ bisects $\angle TAD$.

I have puzzled over this problem from my book on innovative Euclidean Geometry for months.

The book doesn't have solutions, only hints so you can imagine how frustrating this can be.

I would REALLY appreciate this if someone could solve it or at least make headway on it.

If you would like the hint provided by my book just ask. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Oh man! I posted the figure thinking it would be useful.;)

Comment: don't worry, (thank goodness the book had a picture in it or I would have got nowhere). :-)

Comment: We would help you, anyway.:)

Comment: Using coordinates, I find that $\angle TAM = \angle DAM = \angle DXA - \angle DBA$. Now to find an elegant proof of this fact  ...

Comment: Do you mean $DBA-DXA$, instead of the other way around? It looks a lot like, in general, $DBA>DXA$, namely.

Comment: I bet the hint is this: If $P$ is the mid-point of the hypotenuse, then $P$ is equidistant from all three vertices.

Comment: No it's not that, but that is indeed useful at least in my sketchy approach.

Comment: OK, was it this? _Hint:_ Show that $TMDA$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: @HSN: Ah, my figure had $X$ between $A$ and $B$. In the OP's figure, I'd have $\angle DYA - \angle DCA$, which is equivalent to $\angle DBA - \angle DXA$. I suppose in the general case, we just take the absolute value.

Comment: @Blue: I can prove that $\angle DAM = \angle DBA - \angle DXA$. But that doesn't help, because I can't prove that $\angle TAM = \angle DBA - \angle DXA$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes that was the hint. Good guess!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to show it...

Comment: Perhaps you could somehow prove two of the angles subtended by a side of $TMDA$ were equal or try the converse of Ptolemy's Theorem??? I'm not sure. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\angle TDM &= \angle YDC
\\ &= \angle DYA - \angle DCY \text{ (exterior angle = sum of opposite interior angles in triangle }DCY)
\\ &= \angle MAY - \angle DCY \text{ ($M$ is centre of circle through $XAY$, so $\angle MYA = \angle MAY$)}
\\ &= \angle MAY - \angle DAY \text{ ($D$ is centre of circle through $BAC$, so $\angle DCY = \angle DAY$)}
\\ &= \angle MAD
 \end{align*}

But $\angle TDM = \angle MTD$ (because $M$ is centre of circle through $PTD$, so $MD = MT$). Thus $\angle MTD = \angle MAD$, and so $MTAD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. And $MD = MT$. Hence $\angle TAM = \angle MAD$.

**QED**

Comment: Very Beautiful; thank you SO much. It's amazing how many clever little deductions you have to put together to reach such a result. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, we have to prove that angle TAM equals angle MAD. Because XAY and BAC are right triangles,

- DAY=DCA=*alpha*; ABD=BAD=*90-gamma*
- MAY=MYA=*gamma+alpha* ; MAX=MXA=*90-gamma-alpha*

As you may have noticed, I´m calling angle MAD *alpha*. Then, with these properties in hand, we have:

- ADB=*2gamma* (external angle)
- YDC=*alpha* (We know that angle DYA equals *gamma+alpha*, and it`s external angle of triangle DYC. Since angle DCY equals *gamma*, angle YDC can only be *alpha*)
- TDX=*alpha* (Opposite to angle YDC)
- ADY=*180-2gamma-alpha* (sum of angles in triangle ADY)
- ADT=*2gamma* (shallow angle)

But we have that since M id the midpoint of segment PD, PM=MD=MT. Now, we just have to prove that TMDA is a cyclic quadrilateral, since angle TDM equals *alpha* equals angle MTD (because TM=MD), which gives us that angle TMX=*2alpha*. Please note that I´m saying that we have to prove that TMDA is a cyclic quadrilateral because it would gives us the fact that angle TAM equals *alpha*, since that sum of opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral equals 180 degrees.
But note that we´ve already accomplished that: by the sums of angles in triangle MAY, we have that angle PMA equals *2gamma+2alpha*. But angle PMT equals *2alpha*. Then, angle TMA equals *2gamma*. Hey, angle TDA equals *2gamma*, too! Also, angle MTD equals angle MAD equals *alpha*.
To conclude, because TMDA is a cyclic quadrilateral, angle TMP equals angle TAD. So, angle TAM equals *alpha*, and it`s done.

Comment: It's not true, though, that $\angle MAX = \angle DBA$.

Comment: Ah, true. MÂX= gamma and angle DBA= gamma- alpha. What I wanted to say is that YM=MA=MX -> MÂX=MXA.

Comment: Then $\angle DAB  = \gamma + \alpha$. We already know that $\angle DAC = \pi/2 - \angle DAB$, you can simplify that part. But I don't see how you're finding the angle $PAC$.

Comment: Actually, angle DAB equals _gamma-alpha_, given the fact that angle MAD  equals _alpha_. And now I see that I´ve drawn my figure with the letters named in clockwise and not in anticlockwise order, as it is shown above. Anyway, I typed the angle TAC as PAC. And I perceived an error in my answer: I said that we wanted that angle TAM equals _alpha_, so then angle PAC would be _90-gamma_. But that`s actually wrong; we have that angle CAD equals _90-gamma+alpha_ and angle MAD equals _alpha_, which gives us that angle CAM equals _90-gamma_. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Regarding your previous comment, if the points are as given in the problem statement, $\angle DAB  = \gamma + \alpha$. Regarding your edited answer, you're denoting $\angle MAD$ and $\angle DAY$ by $\alpha$. It's not true that  $\angle MAD = \angle DAY$.

Comment: Well, there was a passage where I said ``As you may have noticed, I´m calling angle MAD alpha``, when I wanted to refer to the angle MAY, despite having said MAD. In fact, MAD is not equal to DAY.

Comment: The previous line says $\angle MAY = \gamma + \alpha$, not $\alpha$.